# python 3.5.1 sorting of multivariate Tuples using 2 sorts and the operator module fn

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

I'm working through 3.5.1 Python and I'm working through basic Tuples. I expanded the basic tuple array by 1 additional variable and I wanted to sort the program by name and then grade.

My code is:

```
l1 = [('lee', 'a', 5, 38), ('kim', 'b', 3, 28), ('jung', 'b', 10, 36)]

sortedl1 = l1.sort(l1, key=itemgetter(0,1))

print ('sorted by name: ', sortedl1)
```

When I run the code, I get a compiler error of:

```
sortedl1 = l1.sort(l1, key=itemgetter(0,1))
TypeError: Argument given by name ('key') and position (1)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you remove `l1` from `sort(l1, key=itemgetter(0,1))`?

Comment: I seem to get "none" as the response.... which if I read my code properly, and test it for itemgetter(1) it should be at least reproducing l1 with the sort for 'a->b'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
sortedl1 = sorted(l1, key=itemgetter(0,1))
```

because

- [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) does not return unlike `sorted`, but just sort the list in-place.
- [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) does not accept positional argument.

Comment: @KevinGuan, But OP tried to print `sortedl1` (return value of the function)

Comment: @Delgan, IMO, usage of `itemgetter()` has no issue here.

Comment: @Delgan: I think the issue you described isn't an issue.

Comment: @falsetru: I know, I meant about the second issue you said: *`list.sort` does not accept positional argument.* However, `list.sort` also accepts `key` argument.

Comment: @KevinGuan, It should be a keyword argument, not a positional argument. Try yourself :) http://i.imgur.com/2Jof35K.png

Comment: @falsetru: *Oops, right. Forgot about that part :P*

Comment: Thank you very much falsetru. I understand it now and grateful for the assist (and learning how to indent my code for proper readability)